# Add call with Teams button in React Web App with TypeScript (Multiple Numbers/Buttons)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wildcard, call, microsoft-teams

I'm struggling by integrate a button which can open a Teams call to a specific person.

Would it be possible to add a phone number to my React TypeScript Web App, how would it be done?

Is it possible to get automatically a small contact card or something like that?

Probably you can give me an easy solution like clicking on a phone number and it asks to open Teams, something like that?

This one **DID NOT** helped me a lot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Thanks for your help wish you all the best.

Comment: Best way would be to use deeplink which will show you a pop-up when button is clicked to call the person mention in it. What error you are facing in it?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot it helped me by using:   `{ <a href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=firstname.name@company.com"> (Name of the person) </a> }`

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using following code:

`{ <a href="https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=firstname.name@company.com"> (Name of the person) </a> }`

This creates a clickable link and shows a popup with the question to open Teams in Edge/Chrome etc. as shown below:

[image: Picture shows popup to open Microsoft Teams]

Last thing to do is to click on open and you will get a popup in Teams:

[image: Do you want to call the person]

Wish you all a great day!